# entity data retrieval

Tags: sql, database

I need help with pulling data from a simple entity using sql Server.

The inventory entity has columns`(pk,fk)product_id, (pk,fk)warehouse_id, inventory_amount, inventory_max_stock, inventory_reorder_point`.

I need inventory records as a list of product ID and the sum of the following columns: inventory amount, inventory max stock and inventory reorder point. Show only those results where `inventory_amount > 900`.

```
SELECT PRODUCT_ID, SUM(INVEN_AMOUNT), SUM(INVEN_MAX_STOCK),
SUM(INVEN_REORDER_POINT) FROM INVENTORY
GROUP BY PRODUCT_ID HAVING INVEN_AMOUNT > 900;
```

That is the code that I have tried. But I keep getting the error that its not a group by expression. Any help on why I get that error?

Answer (score 0):

`HAVING INVEN_AMOUNT > 900` isn't allowed since you aren't grouping by `INVEN_AMOUNT`.  Use WHERE instead:

```
SELECT PRODUCT_ID, SUM(INVEN_AMOUNT), SUM(INVEN_MAX_STOCK), SUM(INVEN_REORDER_POINT)
FROM INVENTORY
WHERE INVEN_AMOUNT > 900
GROUP BY PRODUCT_ID;
```

If you want to limit those groups with sums > 900, then use `SUM(INVEN_AMOUNT)`:

```
SELECT PRODUCT_ID, SUM(INVEN_AMOUNT), SUM(INVEN_MAX_STOCK), SUM(INVEN_REORDER_POINT)
FROM INVENTORY
GROUP BY PRODUCT_ID 
HAVING SUM(INVEN_AMOUNT) > 900;
```

Answer (score 0):

`INVEN_AMOUNT` is not validto be used with `having`, But `SUM(INVEN_AMOUNT)` is vaild. `Having` is used for aggregate functions like sum(),avg() and max() etc otherwise use of `where` is better

```
SELECT PRODUCT_ID, SUM(INVEN_AMOUNT) as INVEN_AMOUNT,
SUM(INVEN_MAX_STOCK), SUM(INVEN_REORDER_POINT) FROM INVENTORY
GROUP BY PRODUCT_ID Having SUM(INVEN_AMOUNT) > 900;
```

[**Check Out here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7c353/17)